# Rationals with denominator $1, 2$ or $3$ under addition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do the rationals with denominator $1, 2$ or $3$ form a group under addition if we include $\dfrac{0}{1}$? What if we don't? They clearly have the additive identity if we include $\dfrac{0}{1}$. Associativity and additive inverse is also satisfied. But I'm having trouble proving closure. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Or trying to prove that it's closed and seeing where it seems like you might get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Closure is not satisfied.  For instance, $1/2+1/3=5/6$ is not in the set.